# Why is \paragraph treated as level below \subsubsection?

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs, tex-history

Note: This is meant as a question about the historical development of LaTeX conventions, and how they influence Editor design, not as question about how to implement it differently.

---

One of my pet-peeves about LaTeX, is how editors treat `\paragraph` as the next level below `\subsubsection`. While this corresponds just fine to how it is implemented by default with `\toclevel@subsubsection=3` and `\toclevel@paragraph=4`, it strikes me as an odd convention.

To me, the concepts of paragraph and (sub)<sup>n</sup>sections are entirely distinct, with sectioning defining  a top-level structure of the document, and paragraphs/subparagraphs describing a separate layer of structuring within a given (sub)<sup>n</sup>section; It doesn't make sense for a `\section` to contain a `\subsubsection` directly, but it does make sense for it to contain `\paragraph`s. This view is mirrored by the standard setting of `\paragraph`s not appearing in the table of contents, not being numbered, having their title styled entirely different from sections, and simply by having a distinct command-name pattern.

Now, as long as no deeper nesting than subsubsections are needed – and it is probably bad style to have a deeper level of nesting in final documents – this distinction doesn't matter much. It does however start to matter, when editing document structure with editor tools ("promote/demote subtree"), as they tend to convert subsubsections to paragraphs and vice versa. (Depending on the editor this can be changed though.)

So I was wondering, how did that convention come about?

Comment: I simply think that Lamport didn't want to go to `\subsubsubsection` and he (wrongly) chose `\paragraph`. Bad choice, that's all.

Comment: @egreg Lamport could have gone `\sub3section{}` where the number indicates the depth of the section. but that's all water under the bridge now.

Comment: @naphaneal: Well, it should have been `\subThreeSection`, or something like that… :-)

Comment: Using ``\subsubsubsection`` would have allowed to get a nicely formatted visual outline by doing a ``grep "section{"`` though.

Comment: See also the interview of Leslie Lamport ([here](http://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/lamport-latex-interview.pdf) or [here](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb22-1-2/tb70lamp.pdf)) (see 2nd column of page 2, continuing onto page 3), where something related is touched upon. (Not exactly an answer to your question.)

Comment: note that whatever the merits of the command name, `\paragraph` _is_ the level below `\subsubsection`in latex  so rather than changing editors not to honour that, it would be better to introduce a new command for formal headed paragraphs that are not part of the section hierarchy if they are needed for some document type.

Comment: @David Carlisle — Ultimately I decided to do just that. No amount of increased consistency can compensate having to reconfigure the editors. Sadly this just means that standard LaTeX classes have no concept of "header within a section" or however one would call it, and require changing the formatting of paragraph and below if one wants to make the distinction.

Comment: @kdb The scrjura package implements a concept of clauses ( = headings) and numbered paragraphs. I'm using it for writing contracts according to German standards.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Historically speaking this is inherited from Scribe (designed by Brian Reid in 1979 or so). This system heavily influenced many decisions that Leslie made and you can trace a lot of LaTeX back to choices made by Brian originally.

In the Scribe user manual from 1980 there is

```
  @Section
  @Subsection
  @Paragraph
```

for @Article with and additional @Chapter for @Report and @Book documents.

Notice the name correspondence also for what LaTeX these days called document classes.

So it looks like Leslie invented "subsubsection" as he wanted more heading levels, but that otherwise the names come from Scribe.

Comment: A bad decision nonetheless

Comment: @egrep maybe in hindsight. But on the whole I think Leslie made the right decision in following scribe closely.  A) the basic concepts have been good and B) he had a user base to move over --- and we all know what kind of outcry results from us, say, changing a bad but widely used interface .

Comment: I know little about Scribe or the background of its authors but this concept of a paragraph as a sub^n section seems to exist in legal work (where it may be numbered)

Comment: OK, +1; but this just shifts the question to:  Why did Brian Reid treat `@Paragraph` as a level bwlow `@Subsection`?

Comment: @GuM this is now getting into the guesswork area and I dound you find anybody who knows what went on in Brian's mind at the time (unless there is some information in his PhD thesis about his reasoning on that which I doubt). But I think the possible explanation ChrisH offered is fairly plausible.

Comment: I once wrote a class for typesetting International Standard documents. The ISO specifications to authors said that document divisions could be `clause`, `subclause`, `subsubclause` and so on. In the class file I used `\clause`, `\sclause`, `\ssclause` etc instead of `\section` ... `\subparagraph`. What you call things depends on your audience.

Comment: @FrankMittelbach: Fair enough.  I hoped that somebody could, in turn, explain Brian Reid’s decision by linking it to prior tradition or something like that, but of course it’s also interesting to have traced the origin of the idiom up to that point.

Comment: To follow from @ChrisH, A famous example from the movies is Title 11 Chapter 11 Subchapter I Section 1106 Subsection (a) Paragraph (2) of the US Code, which provides that a trustee (in bankruptcy) shall "if the debtor has not done so, file the list, schedule, and statement required...". Legislation is Turing complete, and can redeclare paragraphs as sections (or anything else), as need be. Subsubsection, if there is one, would be lower roman, e.g. (ii), "usually". "Title" is an implicit heading layer.